# How to compile C/C++ code in eclipse Android (NDK)

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

I have successfully installed the Android CDT, NDK and openCV library for android on my machine, now i want to compile [this](https://github.com/bsdnoobz/opencv-code/blob/master/quad-segmentation.cpp) code in my project.

I have successfully compiled the sample OpenCV projects.

but when I copy and pasted the code in link provided above its throwing error like

```
Invalid arguments 'Candidates are:void push_back(const cv::Point_<float> &)'

Invalid arguments 'Candidates are:cv::Point_<float> computeIntersect(cv::Vec<int,int4>, cv::Vec<int,int4>)'

Invalid arguments 'Candidates are:void circle(cv::Mat &, cv::Point_<int>, int, const cv::Scalar_<double> &, int, int, int)'
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In your program not compiled correctly check your jni package Android.mk file

Refer this link:

http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/

Comment: I have successfully compiled the project. you have sent. it showed me the dialog with text "Hello from native code!"